# Struggling with a question at high school level

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Jack has 40 dollars more than Jill. Jack gives 20 dollars to Jill. Then they have the same amount of money.
I found the answer by method of exhaustion, but how can this be solved more elegantly?

Comment: OOps, forgot the question. Sorry! How much money did Jack and Jill start with?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple solutions to this problem because the second constraint is the same as the first.

Answer (score 3):

Call Jack's starting amount $k$ (after the last letter of his name), and Jill's $l$.  Then we know from the first part of the question that $k-l=40$.

The second part says if $k$ is lowered by 20 and $l$ is raised by 20, they are equal.  So $k-20 = l+20$.  With basic algebra, this translates to $k-l=40$, so we get the same requirement as the first condition.

This means that **any** starting amount for Jack will work, provided it is 40 or higher.  Then set Jill's amount as 40 less, and the second constraint will also work.